# How can I create Switch accounts in other nationalities?

Tags: nintendo-switch, nintendo-account

I have a Switch and all the player accounts registered on it are based in the EU.

I've just been sent a code via a publisher for a US version of a game - they'd run out of EU codes. I've struggled to use international codes before having previously understood that you could just change the "region" system setting on the Switch console.

The publisher told me that I'd need to create a new US-based account to do this. But I'm not really clear on how to go about this, or whether I can use it on my Switch without fiddling with the region setting every time.

Is there any way I can redeem this code on my existing EU account and play the game without having to change the settings whenever I want to play? If not, how do I go about creating an additional US account to redeem the code and adding it to my Switch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't done this since downloading the Monster Hunter XX demo, but if I recall correctly it was surprisingly easy.

First up make a new Nintendo account at https://accounts.nintendo.com/register.  When making this account, set the country/region to wherever you want the account to be "from".

Secondly, once you've completed registration, now make a new account on your switch and link it to that Nintendo account you just made.  This account is now tied to that country/region.

Finally, go to the shop *from that account*.  This will take you to the shop for that Country/Region and you can purchase and use codes normally.  Once you've gotten something this way any of your accounts should be able to play it, so you don't have to worry about any awkward switching after that point.

Note that one side effect of this is that you will get news from all the countries/regions that you have accounts for so you may notice your news on the switch getting more cluttered than normal.  Though with your scenario they should at least all most likely be in the same language.

Comment: Presumably you can't just delete the account when done? If so, that will make several system UIs more annoying, because you cannot disable the account picker when the Switch has multiple accounts.

Comment: @Kevin I believe the downloaded game is tied to that account, so it will not allow you to continue to play the game without that account on the switch with it as its main device.  If that was not the case, friends could share their libraries by attaching their account to other switches long enough to download purchased games, then removing the account once the games were downloaded.  For what it's worth though, I've noticed minimal UI delay with a once per launch account picker.  The prompt is quick to come up and I think has the last selected account as default.